# How to make a scroll as real as clicking the scroll bar arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, onhover

I want to simulate the scroll bar arrows' clicks by hovering certain elements.
Basic example:

```js
function scrollBody(dir, speed){
    $('html, body').animate(
        {'scrollTop': dir+'='+speed+'px'},
        {duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'}
    );
};
$('#top').hover(function(){scrollBody('-', '50')});
$('#bottom').hover(function(){scrollBody('+', '50')});
$('#top-fast').hover(function(){scrollBody('-', '150')});
$('#bottom-fast').hover(function(){scrollBody('+', '150')});
```

```css
#content{width: 300px}
.scroller{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    right:0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 35px;
}
.scroller:hover{background-color:green}
#top{top:35px}
#bottom{bottom:35px}
#top-fast{top:0}
#bottom-fast{bottom:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
</div>
<div id="top" class="scroller">
  2Top
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="scroller">
  2Bot
</div>
<div id="top-fast" class="scroller">
  2T++
</div>
<div id="bottom-fast" class="scroller">
  2B++
</div>
```

I know, it's very simple and worse, it has hiccups... You need to move the cursor around in order to keep it scrolling.
I want to turn it into a continuous smooth scroll.

After this I [simply turned it recursively (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/46/) but I got *stack overflow* (console), should I use `stopPropagation` at some point (after a few recursions) or a loop instead using the hover's toggle (to stop when not hovering) or something else?

If you know other ways (without jQuery-UI to smooth it or even without jQuery at all) I will appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give all the elements you want this hover behaviour for, a certain class.
Dirty check if the mouse is above those elements.
Send corresponding clicks/activate scrolling, at desired pace, or as long as the hover is active.

**Update**:

Here is a working snippet. Nothing changed in the fiddle other than JS.
It's got a bit of a delay to stop scrolling because of the timeout.
Relevant docs:

```
var actions;

function scroll(dir, speed){
        $('html, body').animate(
        {'scrollTop': dir+'='+speed+'px'},
        {duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'}
        );
};

function startScroll(dir, speed){
    actions = setTimeout(function(){
        scroll(dir, speed);
        startScroll(dir, speed);
    }, 300);

};

function endScroll(){
    clearTimeout(actions);    
}
$('#top').hover(function(){startScroll('-', '50')}, endScroll);
$('#bottom').hover(function(){startScroll('+', '50')}, endScroll);
$('#top-fast').hover(function(){startScroll('-', '150')}, endScroll);
$('#bottom-fast').hover(function(){startScroll('+', '150')}, endScroll);
```

[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), especially the 2nd callback on mouse leaving.
[clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp), since we need it to turn off the scrolling and stop the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, in my snippet all elements have the `scroller` class, I assigned an hover event to each of them individually, and animated them accordingly. Can you provide a snippet with your idea? (btw, copy mine, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look on fiddle. You're really close though. Essentially, I'd be trying to take advantage of [hover's `handlerOut` function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). So your first function would be starting the scrolling in a given direction, and your second function would end the scrolling. I'd have to look up docs for clearing/stopping. Does that help?

Comment: Updated. Not pretty, but should get you well on your way. Please clean it up!

Comment: +1 Thank you very much :) Very creative, never imagined that way! [Here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/47/). However, I still want to find a way to stop the hiccups (pausing and starting). I will mark the answer as accepted later if no one figures it out.

Comment: The hiccups just have to do with the longer timeouts. Try playing around with them, delay and distance scrolled for each iteration of the infinite loop. (Although it's fair to assume that it will slow down again as your application gets really big.)